# Lipschitz function to $\mathbb{R}^3$ on unit square in $\mathbb{R}^2$ has zero content

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, proof-verification

Consider the set $X = [0,1] \times [0,1] \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$, and let 
$f: X \to \mathbb{R}^3$ be a Lipschitz function. Prove that the 
image-set $Y = f(X) \subseteq \mathbb{R}^3$ is a zero-content subset 
of $\mathbb{R}^3$.

My approach:

*(I think the idea is correct, but I've got confused with my epsilons. Can you please help me define them properly, especially the $\varepsilon'$?)*

$\newcommand{\ee}{ \varepsilon }$
$\newcommand{\xx}{ \vec{x} }$
$\newcommand{\yy}{ \vec{y} }$
$\newcommand{\bR}{ {\mathbb{R}} }$

> Let $\Delta$ be a division of $X$ into $N^2$ half-open rectangles $P^2_{i,j}$ (for $1\le i,j\le N$, and where $P_{i,j}\subset X$ is a rectangle in $\bR^2$) in $\bR^3$ (that is, each rectangle $P^2_{i,j}$ is a three-dimensional solid cube in the usual sense). Let $\ee > \frac{1}{N}$, then $\sum_{i=1}^N \sum_{j=1}^N \mbox{vol}_0(P^2_{i,j})=N^2 \frac{1}{N^3} = \frac1N < \ee$. (Hence, $X$ is zero-content in $\bR^3$). Now, since $f$ is Lipschitz on $X$, there exists a constant $c>0$ such that $\|f(\xx)-f(\yy)\|\le c\|\xx-\yy\|$ for all $\xx, \yy\in X$. Let $\ee'^2> c^2\ee \cdot / N^2$. Let $\xx, \yy\in P_{i,j}$ for some $1\le i,j\le N$, then $\|f(\xx)-f(\yy)\|^2\le c^2\|\xx-\yy\|^2\le c^2 \ee < N^2 \cdot \ee'^2$. Since $f(P_{i,j})$ completely cover $f(X)$ and $\sum_{i=1}^N \sum_{j=1}^N \mbox{vol}_0(f(P_{i,j}))\le c\cdot \sqrt{\ee} < \ee'$, $f(X)$ is zero-content.

To generalize this to higher dimensions, we consider $f: X\to \bR^n$, where $X\subseteq \bR^{n-1}$ is the hyperplane $\underbrace{[0,1]\times \dots \times [0,1]}_\text{$n-1$ times}$. Let $\Delta$ be a division of $X$ into $N^{n-1}$ half-open rectangles $P_{i_1,\dots, i_{n-1}}$ (for $1\le i_1,\dots, i_{n-1}\le N$) in $\bR^n$. Let $\ee > \frac{1}{N}$, then $\sum_{i_1=1}^N \dots \sum_{i_{n-1}=1}^N \mbox{vol}_0(P_{i_1,\dots,i_{n-1}})=N^{n-1} \frac{1}{N^n} = \frac1N < \ee$. (Hence, $X$ is zero-content in $\bR^n$). Now, since $f$ is Lipschitz on $X$, there exists a constant $c>0$ such that $\|f(\xx)-f(\yy)\|\le c\|\xx-\yy\|$ for all $\xx, \yy\in X$. Let $\ee'> \frac{c\sqrt2}{N^n}$. Let $\xx, \yy\in P_{i_1,\dots,i_{n-1}}$ for some $1\le i_1,\dots,i_{n-1}\le N$, then $\|f(\xx)-f(\yy)\|\le c\|\xx-\yy\|=c \cdot \frac{\sqrt{2}}{N^{n-2}}< \ee'/N^2$. Since $f(P_{i_1,\dots,i_{n-1}})$ completely cover $f(X)$ and $\sum_{i_1=1}^N \dots \sum_{i_{n-1}=1}^N \mbox{vol}_0(f(P_{i_1,\dots,i_n}))\le c\cdot \sqrt2 N < \ee'$, $f(X)$ is zero-content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not understood why you cover $X$ with three-dimensional cubes.

I think you can simplify your proof in this way.
Let $P_{ij}$ be a cover of $X$ with $N^2$ squares of size $1/N$, and let $x_{ij}$ denote the center of $P_{ij}$.

Let $L> 0$ be the Lipschitz constant of $f$. Since
$$
|f(x) - f(x_{ij}| \leq L |x - x_{ij}| \leq L\, \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2 N} =: r,
\qquad\forall x\in P_{ij},
$$
you have that $f(P_{ij})$ is contained in a three-dimensional ball of radius $r$ centered at $f(x_{ij}$, hence
$$
vol(f(X)) \leq \sum_{ij} vol(f(P_{ij})) \leq N^2 \, \frac{4\pi}{3} r^3 = \frac{C}{N}\,.
$$
From this inequality you can conclude that that $vol(f(X)) = 0$.