# Open and closed unit balls are Jordan measurable

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, lipschitz-functions

It has earlier been [proved](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2360279/lipschitz-function-to-mathbbr3-on-unit-square-in-mathbbr2-has-zero-c) that the image of a function $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}^3$ has zero content on $X:=[0,1]\times [0,1]$. Now I would like to prove that the open and closed unit balls in $\mathbb{R}^3$ are Jordan measurable. For a set to be Jordan measurable one has to ensure that the set is bounded and that its boundary has zero content.

My approach is to devise a function $f:X\to S^2\subset \mathbb{R}^3$, where $S^2$ is a unit sphere (either open or closed), and prove that it is Lipschitz. Then it will follow that the boundary of a unit ball in $\mathbb{R}^3$ has zero-content, and thus a unit ball, being a bounded set with a zero-content boundary, is Jordan measurable.

> So let $f$ be defined as $f((x,y))=(x,y,\pm\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2})$, then $\|f(x,y)-f(s,t)\|\le\sqrt{(x-s)^2+(y-t)^2+1}\le \sqrt3$, and $\|(x,y)-(s,t)\|\le \sqrt2$. Let $c:=2$ be a constant, then it follows that $\|f(x,y)-f(s,t)\|\le c\|(x,y)-(s,t)\|$. Hence $f$ is Lipschitz on $X$. It follows that $S^2$ has zero content in $\mathbb{R}^3$. Since a unit ball is a bounded set, it follows that it is Jordan measurable.

Please let me know if my approach is correct. I'm a little bit concerned about my proof of the Lipschitz condition.

Answer (score 1):

There are some problems with this. Some more glaring than others.

1. What do you mean $f((x,y)) = (x,y,\color{red}{\pm}\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2})$? This is not a well-defined function.
2. Even if it were well-defined, this function is not defined on all of $X$. For instance at $x=y=1$, your function's $z$-coordinate is not real.
3. I'm not sure you are taking the correct approach proving that $f$ is Lipschitz. You need to demonstrate that there exists a $C>0$ such that given $x,y\in X$, $|f(x)-f(y)|\le C|x-y|$, as you know. However, you are computing $\sup_{x,y}|f(x)-f(y)|$ and $\sup_{x,y}|x-y|$, and comparing them, which does not convince me that the function is Lipschitz.

You could do better by defining two separate functions $f_+$ and $f_-$ from $X\to \Bbb R^3$ as such:
$$
f_{\pm}(x,y) = \begin{cases} (x,y,\pm\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}) & (x,y)\in B^2, \\ (x,y,0) & (x,y)\in X\setminus B^2,\end{cases}
$$
where $B^2\subset\Bbb R^2$ is the open unit ball. Showing these functions are Lipschitz on $B^2$ would suffice to show they are Lipschitz on $X$. For Lipschitz on $B^2$, note that $f_\pm$ are smooth on $B^2$ and that $B^2$ is convex. Then use the fact that the image of each of $f_\pm$ is measure $0$ by the theorem you cite and that the union of their images contains $S^2$ to conclude that $S^2$ has measure $0$.

Comment: 1. This is actually a non-rigorous definition of two functions.
2. I think that one condition is missing, that is that $(x^2+y^2)\le 1$. Will this then make $f$ well-defined? Can you think of a better function taking $X$ to $S^2$?
3. Consider $\nabla f = (1,1,0)$, then $\|\nabla f\|=\sqrt2$, and by the MVT we can conclude that $\|f(x,y)-f(s,t)\|\le \sqrt2\|(x,y)-(s,t)\|$.

Comment: @sequence Please confer with my updated answer.

Comment: Why do we need to care about convexity of $B^2$? @AOrtiz

Comment: @sequence The multivariable mean value theorem you cite relies on the domain of the function in question being convex. Confer with Baby Rudin's theorem 9.19, for instance. There may be other conditions on which you get a mean value-like theorem to hold, but since the ball $B^2$ is convex, you may as well apply a theorem like Rudin's 9.19.

Comment: @sequence Ok, I edited my answer again. I believe this is all correct as written now. Let me know if you have any more questions.

Comment: Can you please let me know if this is correct? Since $X$ is convex, we can apply the Mean Value Theorem: $\|\nabla f\| = \|(1,1,0)\|=\sqrt2 $, so that $\|f_\pm(x,y)-f(s,t)\|\le \sqrt2 \|(x,y)-(s,t)\|$, for $(x,y), (s,t)\in S$. Hence $f_\pm$ is Lipschitz on $X$. By a similar argument, $f_\pm$ is Lipschitz on $X' := [-1,0]\times [-1, 0]$ and $X''=[0,-1]\times [0, -1]$ and $X'''=[0,-1]\times [-1, 1]$. But $B^2\subset X\cup X'\cup X''\cup X'''$, thus $f_\pm$ is Lipschitz on $B^2$. Hence, $S^2$ has zero content in $\mathbb{R}^3$. @AOrtiz

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62325/discussion-between-aortiz-and-sequence).